# How to find all the usages to instance variable object throughout call graph?

Tags: java, parsing, callstack

From an existing code base. Class A has a instance variable A.toBeCalled as type "ToBeCalled".
How to find all the usage/reference to it A.toBeCalled throughout call graph from code base?
e.g.

- Class B calls to A.getToBeCalled() and store in its local var, then use it by calling its method.
- Class B calls to A.getToBeCalled() and store in Class C's instance var, then Class D uses Class C's instance var.

Requirement:

- What methods call to A.toBeCalled object had done in Class B, Class C, Class D...e.t.c
- The callee graph for above

Code example

```
Class A {
   ToBeCalled toBeCalled = new ToBeCalled();
   getToBecalled() { return toBeCalled;}
}

Class B {      
  main() {
    A a = new A();
    ToBeCalled toBeCalledInB = a.getToBecalled();
    toBeCalledInB.doXXX();
    C c = new C();
    c.setToBeCalled(toBeCalledInB);
    D d = new D();
    d.start(c);
  }
}

Class C {
  ToBeCalled toBeCalledInC;
  setToBeCalled(ToBeCalled theToBeCalled){
    toBeCalledInC = theToBeCalled;
  }
  getToBeCalled() {
    return toBeCalledInC;
  }
}

Class D {
  start(C c) {
    ToBeCalled toBeCalledInD = c.getToBeCalled();
    toBeCalledInD.doYYY();
  }
}
```

List method invoked to A.toBeCalled

- ToBeCalled.doXXX()
- ToBeCalled.doYYY()

I had surveyed for several tools as start point, however,they are kind of rough

- https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser
- IntelliJ's Code Explorer plugin
- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+4+Documentation
- http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/Doc/FAQ

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Maybe I'm noob programmer, but I didn't understand your question at all. The same thing with example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, maybe my expression required adjustment. I was meaning how to list all usages of a instance var from a class across all its caller classes.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I rephrased my question, hope it's now easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you are talking about `interfaces`.
Lets say you have interface `MyItf` with several methods:

```
public interface MyItf {
public ToBeCalled getToBeCalled();
public void doXXX();
public void doYYY();
}
```

By using `interface`  `ToBeCalled` class must override all methods.

```
public class ToBeCalled implements MyItf{

@Override
public ToBeCalled getToBeCalled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void doXXX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doYYY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class ToBeCalled2 implements MyItf{

@Override
public ToBeCalled getToBeCalled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void doXXX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doYYY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

finally:

```
public class Launcher {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyItf my = new ToBeCalled();        
    my.getToBeCalled();     
    my.doXXX();     
    my.doYYY();

            my = new ToBeCalled2();     
    my.getToBeCalled();     
    my.doXXX();     
    my.doYYY();
}
}
```

Comment: I rephrased my question, hope now it's easier to understand.